# Limit an Intel i5 CPU 8th generation

Tags: cpu-frequency

I would like to throttle my CPU, I have an i5-8265U and it has frequencies up to 3.9GHz, but I rarely need the speed.

Now if something causes a high load, the CPU goes up and the fan gets noisy.

It is already set to `powersave`

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
```

And `userspace` is not available, when I try

```
sudo cpufreq-set -f 2.0
```

How do I throttle such a CPU to max 2GHz?

Comment: Maybe https://blog.christophersmart.com/2017/02/08/manage-intel-turbo-boost-with-systemd/

Comment: Or https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu

Comment: Doens't BIOS have this option?

Comment: My Lenovo yoga 730 doesn't seem to have such option in BIOS

Comment: Maybe you could try pressing F2 or DEL key on splash image during boot up then access its BIOS. There may have CPU control options, like "Quiet Mode", Overclocking and others.

Comment: Even if it had this. A better soluton is to disable it one minute after boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have such a setting in your BIOS, the solution is solved quite well here for Linux: http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2014/11/a-script-to-turn-off-intel-cpu-turbo.html

I created an enhanced version of that script to toggle the turbo boost here on GitHub:
https://github.com/rubo77/intel-turbo-boost

---

Old version:

just create a `/usr/local/sbin/turbo-boost.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

is_root () {
    return $(id -u)
}

has_sudo() {
    local prompt

    prompt=$(sudo -nv 2>&1)
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # has_sudo__pass_set
        return 0
    elif echo $prompt | grep -q '^sudo:'; then
        # has_sudo__needs_pass"
        return 0
    else
        echo "no_sudo"
        return 1
    fi
}

if ! is_root && ! has_sudo; then
    echo "Error: need to call this script with sudo or as root!"         
    exit 1
fi

modprobe msr
if [[ -z $(which rdmsr) ]]; then
    echo "msr-tools is not installed. Run 'sudo apt-get install msr-tools' to install it." >&2
    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! -z "$1" && "$1" != "toggle" && "$1" != "enable" && "$1" != "disable" ]]; then
    echo "Invalid argument: $A" >&2
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: $(basename $0) [disable|enable|toggle]"
    exit 1
fi

A=$1
cores=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | awk '{print $3}')
initial_state=$(rdmsr -p1 0x1a0 -f 38:38)
for core in $cores; do
    if [[ $A == "toggle" ]]; then
        echo -n "state was "
        if [[ $initial_state -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo "disabled"
            A="enable"
        else
            echo "enabled"
            A="disable"
        fi
    fi
    if [[ $A == "disable" ]]; then
        wrmsr -p${core} 0x1a0 0x4000850089
    fi
    if [[ $A == "enable" ]]; then
        wrmsr -p${core} 0x1a0 0x850089
    fi
    state=$(rdmsr -p${core} 0x1a0 -f 38:38)
    if [[ $state -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo "core ${core}: disabled"
    else
        echo "core ${core}: enabled"
    fi
done
```

give it

```
chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/turbo-boost.sh
```

Now you can call

```
sudo turbo-boost.sh disable
sudo turbo-boost.sh enable
sudo turbo-boost.sh toggle
```

### automatically disable turbo-boost on startup

If you want to autostart this one minute after boot, you can allow the execution without password in `/etc/sudoers` with:

```
# Allow command for my user without password         
my_username_here ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/turbo-boost.sh
```

Then create a systemd startup script with a delay of 60 seconds:

Create the script `/etc/systemd/system/turbo-boost-disable.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=disables turbo-boost

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 60
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/turbo-boost.sh disable

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Update systemd with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable turbo-boost-disable
```

### Add toggle button on desktop

If you more often want to control the turbo-boost manually, you can add a Button to your desktop:

1. `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/toggle-turbo-boost.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=toggle turbo-boost
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/apps/64/gkdebconf-icon.svg
Exec=sudo /usr/local/sbin/turbo-boost.sh toggle
X-MultipleArgs=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;
StartupNotify=true
GenericName=Toggle Turbo-Boost
Path=/tmp/
```

2. press SUPER and search for "Toggle Turbo Boost", you will see the icon.
3. press ENTER to execute, or right click to "Add to Favorites" which will add a button in the quick-start bar.

Comment: I don't know...I control this through BIOS. Your link is to a distro package. BIOS can prohibit changing this, for a reason. You should at least make that more clear. Otherwise: important Q!